# copy/paste on MacOS gets 'Stuck'

Tags: macos, clipboard

SnowLeopard.

I commonly use copy in a terminal window to grab stuff I have to paste. A few times in the last few days, the clipboard has gotten 'stuck' on some old text. I do the copy gesture (with keyboard or Edit menu) in the terminal window. I paste somewhere else, and get something other than what I just copied.

If all else fails, I can always tell the terminal to write it's content to a file and use that. But I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing to get into this pickle and if there's any way out.

**EDIT**

This seems to be provoked by having a great deal of history scrollback on the particular tab. Sometimes the next thing that happens is that Terminal crashes.

Comment: The only times I've had this happen is when I've been working with both my OS-X host and a Windows guest VM. In my case, the alt-keys differ between the two (Cmd-C/Cmd-V and Opt-C/Opt-V) and I'll occasionally use the opposite one.  I.e., it's definitely been a "pilot error"; I don't suspect either system in my case.  Any chance something similar is happening for you?

Comment: Nope, virtual box is not running, and I've carefully used both the keyboard shortcut and the Edit menu with the same surprising results.

Comment: How much is "a great deal of history"?  Also, what is your Scrollback set to in Terminal Preferences?  I see mine is set to 10,000 rows, but I don't know if that's self-entered or a default.

I've seen MS Excel 2008 be cruelly slow to copy something into the Clipboard, but I've never seen this with Terminal.